# Laravel Zipper delete files after zipping

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I am using a [Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) package for making zip files out of API fetched PDF's. Zipping works fine but I would like to delete PDF files that were zipped.

```
$pdf_summary_filename = public_path() . $path . uniqid() . '_summary.pdf';
PDF::loadView('pdf.summary', $pdf_data)->save($pdf_summary_filename);
$zipper->make($zip_filename)->add($pdf_summary_filename);

File::cleanDirectory(public_path() . '/user_downloads');
```

I am using this code, however, I think that `cleanDirectory()` gets called before the zipping finishes, and I see no zip generated. If I comment out the last line, I get both the zip file as well as PDF's in `/user_downloads`.

How can I wait for the zipper to finish zipping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can try below code:

```
$flgFile = $zipper->make($zip_filename)->add($pdf_summary_filename);

if($flgFile){
    File::cleanDirectory(public_path() . '/user_downloads'); 
}
```

This may help you better!

Comment: According to documentation, `remove()` removes a file from zip, doesn't delete added file from the disk